# How to do standard layouts with StringTemplate?

Tags: stringtemplate

With StringTemplate, what is the proper way to have a standard layout template such as:

```
<head>
..
</head>

<html>

$body()$

</html>
```

Where I can set the body template from my application, so that every template I use uses this fundamental layout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it hiding in the documentation:
http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/StringTemplate+2.2+Documentation

> "Include template whose name is
>   computed via expr. The argument-list
>   is a list of attribute assignments
>   where each assignment is of the form
>   attribute=expr. Example
>   $(whichFormat)()$ looks up
>   whichFormat's value and uses that as
>   template name. Can also apply an
>   indirect template to an attribute."

So my main layout template now looks like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Sportello</title>
</head>

<html lang="en-US">
<body>
    $partials/header()$
    <section>$(body_template)()$</section>
    $partials/footer()$
</body>
</html>
```

...to which I pass the subtemplate's name as an attribute.